# How to post UIImage on friends wall through Facebook using iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, fbconnect

I'm using the social framework to attach text and an image to share on Facebook and twitter but the sharing is done on my wall. I need to add the option to post on a friend's wall.
My code as follows

`“AttachmentTableViewController.h”`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SocialSharingViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)postToTwitter:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender;

@end

“AttachmentTableViewController.m”
#import <Social/Social.h>

- (IBAction)postToTwitter:(id)sender {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Great fun to learn iOS programming at appcoda.com!"];
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender {
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [controller setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];        
    }
}
```

This code posts on my wall but I need to add the possibility to share on my friends' wall. Any help please.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Posting on a friend's wall is not allowed anymore.

Comment: so we can't post on the friends timeline through iPhone app.

Comment: we can make tag for friends; kindly if you know a tutorial